# Check if upsert necessary

Tags: callout, rest, upsert, externalid

I am using external id and rest callout to another org, but is there a way to check if i need to make callout? Cause callout called even if all fields are the same. I can compare all fields, but its a bad way.

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/Line_Item__c/LineItemExtID__c/456
```

Comment: I suspect you have been downvoted due to lack of detail in your question. Can you add some detail about why you are making the callout, and the criteria for when you don't think you need to? What's the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing all non-system fields can easily be checked like this:

```
sObject[] changedRecords = new sObject[0];
for(Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.size; i++) {
  if(Trigger.old[i].clone(false, false, false, false) != 
     Trigger.new[i].clone(false, false, false, false)) {
    changedRecords.add(Trigger.new[i]);
}
if(changedRecords.size() > 0) {
  doCallouts(changedRecords);
}
```

The `==` operator checks if all fields are the same, while `!=` checks if any field is different. We use the clone method to clear out all non-essential fields (such as `LastModifiedDate`), which may always show up as modified in an after trigger; we're only interested in user edits.